# Apache vhost not redirecting to local configuration

Tags: php, apache, apache2, localhost, vhosts

Setting up a localhost server using the LAMP stack, and cannot get it to redirect the PHP header to my local configuration. I've edited the default apache configuration file as so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /home/taylor/keychat/
ServerName keychat.vkv.me
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /home/taylor/keychat>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/taylor/keychat/
    ServerName keychat.vkv.me
</VirtualHost>
```

This is what is in the "hosts" file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   keychat.vkv.me
127.0.1.1   taylor-VirtualBox
```

keychat.vkv.me is what the PHP files redirect to, and it is still directing there and not to my local files on the vhost. Everything else works fine. Resetting the default vhost and adding a new one did not work, and neither did getting rid of the new one I added at the bottom. What is going on?

Comment: Where do you want to redirect it to? Did you uncomment vhost line in httpd.conf? It should be something like: Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

Comment: I want it to redirect to the local file. The PHP redirects to keychat.vkv.me/somefile and I want it to redirect to localhost/somefile. httpd.conf was empty when I checked it, I tried adding the hosts stuff to it and it didn't work.

Comment: add this entery. Save and restart apache. <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/taylor/
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>